# How to construct 3rd parameter of edai.Search method within CURL request to XPLAN API?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to run a search on an API which requires my query data to be styled as XML nested in an XML request.  I'll post my entire class and method calls (which I sent to iress tech support) so that it can be fully reviewed and in the off-chance that anyone has access to the same API, they can instantly reproduce the issue for themselves.

```
class XMLCurler
{
    private $username = '[redacted]';
    private $password = '[redacted]';
    private $url = 'https://[redacted].xplan.iress.com.au/RPC2/';
    public $ch;     // the curl handle
    public $token;  
    public $results;

    public function __construct() {
        if ($this->connect()) {
            if ($this->login()) {
                echo "<div class=\"success\">Successful Connection & Login. Token: {$this->token}</div>";
            }
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        if ($this->ch) {
            $this->disconnect();
        }
    }

    public function connect() {
        if (!$this->ch = curl_init($this->url)) { // generate curl handle
            echo "<div class=\"error\">CURL Error While Connecting (check url)";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function disconnect() {
        curl_close($this->ch);
    }

    public function processResponse($response) {
        if (!$response) {
            echo "<div class=\"error\">CURL Error While Attempting to Login - No XML token string<br><b>" , curl_error($this->ch) , "</b></div>";
            return false;
        }
        $decoded = xmlrpc_decode($response);
        if (is_array($decoded) && xmlrpc_is_fault($decoded)) {
            echo "<div class=\"error\">Error Response: {$decoded['faultString']} ({$decoded['faultCode']})</div>";
            return false;
        }
        return $decoded;    
    }

    public function login() {
        $postfields = xmlrpc_encode_request('edai.Login', array($this->username, $this->password));  // package as xml
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);      // not advised, I need to find out how to avoid this
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);      // not advised, I need to find out how to avoid this

        if (!$token = $this->processResponse(curl_exec($this->ch))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!preg_match("~^[\w+]{20}$~", $token)) {
            echo "<div class=\"error\">Invalid/Unexpected Token Generated<br><b>$token</b>";
            return false;
        }
        $this->token = $token;  // cache the valid token
        return true;
    }

    public function listChildren($path) {
        $method = "edai.ListChildren";
        $request = xmlrpc_encode_request($method, array($this->token, $path));

        echo "<div class=\"notice\">XMLRPC Encoded Request (for $method): <pre>" , htmlentities($request) , "</pre></div>";

        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);       
        if (!$results = $this->processResponse(curl_exec($this->ch))) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->results = $results;  // cache the valid results
        return true;
    }


    public function search($basepath, $queryxml) {
        $method = "edai.Search";

        /** Desperate/Manual xml construction ...
         * $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
         * $xml->appendChild($methodCall = $xml->createElement("methodCall"));
         * $methodCall->appendChild($methodName = $xml->createElement("methodName"));
         * $methodCall->appendChild($params = $xml->createElement("params"));

         * $params->appendChild($param1 = $xml->createElement("param"));
         * $param1->appendChild($value1 = $xml->createElement("value"));
         * $value1->appendChild($string1 = $xml->createElement("string"));

         * $params->appendChild($param2 = $xml->createElement("param"));
         * $param2->appendChild($value2 = $xml->createElement("value"));
         * $value2->appendChild($string2 = $xml->createElement("string"));

         * $params->appendChild($param3 = $xml->createElement("param"));
         * $param3->appendChild($value3 = $xml->createElement("value"));
         * $value3->appendChild($string3 = $xml->createElement("string"));
         * $string3->appendChild($EntitySearch = $xml->createElement("EntitySearch"));
         * $EntitySearch->appendChild($SearchResult1 = $xml->createElement("SearchResult"));
         * $SearchResult1->setAttribute("field", "first_name");

         * $EntitySearch->appendChild($SearchResult2 = $xml->createElement("SearchResult"));
         * $SearchResult2->setAttribute('field', "last_name");

         * $EntitySearch->appendChild($SearchQuick = $xml->createElement("SearchQuick"));
         * $SearchQuick->appendChild($s = $xml->createElement("s"));

         * $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
         * $result1 = $xpath->query("//methodName");
         * $result1->item(0)->nodeValue = $method;

         * $result2 = $xpath->query("//params/param[1]/value/string");
         * $result2->item(0)->nodeValue = $this->token;
         * $result3 = $xpath->query("//params/param[2]/value/string");
         * $result3->item(0)->nodeValue = "entitymgr/client";

         * $result4 = $xpath->query("//SearchQuick/s");
         * $result4->item(0)->nodeValue = "last_name:Smith";

         * $xml->formatOutput = true;
         * $request = $xml->saveXML();
         */

         /** Desperately attempted passing array ...
          * $queryarray = array(
          *     "EntitySearch" => array(
          *         array(
          *             "SearchResult" => array(
          *                 "@attr" => array(
          *             "field" => "first_name"
          *                 )
          *             )
          *         ),
          *             array(
          *             "SearchResult" => array(
          *                 "@attr" => array(
          *                     "field" => "last_name"
          *                 )
          *             )
          *         ),
          *         array(
          *             "SearchQuick" => array(
          *                 "s" => "last_name:Smith"
          *             )
          *         )
          *     )
          * );
          */

        $request = xmlrpc_encode_request($method, array($this->token, $basepath, $queryxml));  // this mutates the nested $queryxml string
            // Causes:
                //Error Response: UNKNOWN(CORBA.UNKNOWN(omniORB.UNKNOWN_PythonException, CORBA.COMPLETED_MAYBE)) (-32505)
        //$request = html_entity_decode($request);  // repair encoded entities
        //$request = preg_replace('~(?:>\K\s+)|(?:\s+(?=<))~', '', $request);  // strip every whitespace character between tags (hack)
            // Causes:
                // Error Response: ExpatError(syntax error: line 1, column 0 (byte 0)) (-32505)
        echo "<div class=\"notice\">XMLRPC Encoded Request (for $method): <pre>" , htmlentities($request) , "</pre></div>";

        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
        if (!$results = $this->processResponse(curl_exec($this->ch))) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->results = $results;  // cache the valid results
        return true;
    }
}
```

Below is how I make the calls.  `edai.ListChildren` works because I don't have to send any XML data.  `edai.Search` does not work because I am failing to properly prepare the XML query within the XML request.

```
$XC = new XMLCurler();

/* edai.ListChildren works as desired/expected */
$path = "/entitymgr/client";
if ($XC->listChildren($path)) {
    echo "<div>List of Children Successful.<pre>";
    var_export($XC->results);
    echo "</pre></div>";
}

/* edai.Search does not work */
$basepath = "entitymgr/client";
$queryxml = <<<XML
<EntitySearch>
 <SearchResult field="first_name"/>
 <SearchResult field="last_name"/>
 <SearchQuick><s>last_name:Smith</s></SearchQuick>
</EntitySearch>
XML;
if ($XC->search($basepath, $queryxml)) {
    echo "<div>Search Successful.<pre>";
    var_export($XC->results);
    echo "</pre></div>";
}
```

This is [the attempted request and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4ECH.jpg).

This is [the relevant portion of the manual I was provided (XPLAN XML-RPC EXTERNAL DATA ACCESS INTERFACE 7 May 2013)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yQdA.jpg):

I have contacted iress.com a couple of weeks ago, they called me to loosely confirm that I was authorized to access the API, and told me that they'd be in touch -- that follow up call hasn't happened and I would like to get back to work on this project.

I do know for a fact that there is a last name of `Smith` to match my query.

I have no Python experience so the error responses are no help to me.  I have made more *hail mary* attempts than I have posted, but I am tired of wasting my time.  I don't know if the third parameter is meant to be nested inside of a `<value>`, `<param>`, `<struct>`, `<string>`, `<array>`, `<xml>`, or something else entirely.

If anyone has any suggestions regarding how to prepare my XML query for the request, I'll run them and supply feedback.

I am also happy to receive advice on the class design, security concerns, and completely different php approaches for getting the `edai.Search` to return some useful data.

---

As requested by @ThW, here is a collection of xml attempts and their respective error responses: https://pastebin.com/dYtwXWxz

Comment: To clarify, I am seeking php support, but the python tag is included because my error responses are in python -- see commented attempts and error responses near the bottom of my class code block.

Comment: I suggest stripping it down to a simple curl request with a static XML. After that works, you can analyze the difference.

Comment: The issue is isolated to the `search` method of my class.  Even if I was to manually/statically write the 3-parameter xml without `xmlrpc_encode_request()`, I simply don't know the correct syntax.  I have tried many combinations  (more than I care to post).  Anyhow, I'll take that suggestion and try a few hardcoded attempts.

Comment: @ThW I have just edited my question to include a batch of hardcoded xml strings being fed to curl.  The error response immediately follows each attempt.  Please have a look if you have a moment.  I am happy to fire off any other logical suggestions.

Comment: The Python errors are of no help to anyone here, as we don’t have access to the source of the server. They invariably mean that your request is not conforming to the expected SOAP API method call expectations. Try to find a working static example and work your way back from that

Comment: Suddenly IRESS have freed themselves of any involvement and have trashed my support ticket claiming that it is another company's responsibility (the redacted portion of the `$url` value).  This new company promises to be in contact within two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the error was not in my php code (which I have since developed further to better handle the response data), but rather the xml query that I was sending.

Instead of using what the documentation suggested:

```
<SearchQuick><s>last_name:Smith</s></SearchQuick>
```

Use the following equivalent valid expression:

```
<SearchByField field="last_name" op="equal"><s>Smith</s></SearchByField>
```

Answer (score 2):

A shot in the dark, since I can't test the API directly...

Perhaps the xmlrpc_encode_request call could do with named params:

```
$params = [
    'context' => $this->token,
    'basepath' => $basepath, // try with a leading slash, too, in spite of the docs listing it w/o one
    'queryxml' => $queryxml,
];
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request($method, $params);  // this mutates the nested $queryxml string
```

If that doesn't work, stop messing around with the code and install [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) or similar, and manually construct your requests.

I suspect you'll have a working request within a half-hour, and can work backwards from that to debug your code / rewrite your code. I'd do it for you if I had access to the API.

Things to check:

- does the encoding make a difference (should it be utf8 instead of )?
- the XML query needs to be treated as a string, so make sure it winds up encoded / wrapped in CDATA tags when your GUI client makes its requests. Depending on the client you pick it may be done for you, just make sure its done

Comment: I just tried (many combinations of the following): keying the elements (No), adding slash after basepath (No, syntax errors on `$queryxml` precede this value's usage anyhow), wrapping the hardcoded/nested queryxml string in `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` (No)  added `<meta charset="utf-8">` (No)  Thank you for your offerings, but none of the above was useful.  I am not going to entertain installing additional software at this point -- at least not until API support has come back to me saying that my overall approach can't work (which I am sure it will with some adjustment).

Comment: Do what works for you, but installing the extra software is actually a simplifying effort, not a complicating one. You're still wrestling, in part, with the code, including an experimental PHP function. Getting away from all that garbage and just making a few plain ol' HTTP requests could do a lot to help find a way forward.

Comment: At this point, I'm not using the experimental call while seeking a solution.  After I can determine the right syntax, I'll investigate if the function is impeding success.

Answer (score 2):

After personally speaking to IRESS support and continued investigation, unfortunately (and despite a manual being written which expresses how to integrate with the API), the only licensed usage of the API is for "uploading documents with a Toshiba scanner".

To gain access, new license paperwork will need to be drawn up by the legal teams from IRESS and the company in the above redacted url.  This is not likely to be a speedy endeavour.